# Create a new Column in a Document Library for # of Items in a Folder

Tags: 2013, document-library

I have a document library with many different folders, and I want to add an additional column that displays the number of items in each folder. Is this possible? I know how to get the create column menu, but at that point I'm not sure how to get the number of items. I have access to SharePoint Designer, but I'm not well versed. If the solution to this requires any coding, you'll have to really explain where I have to go to put the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the view and add below fields

1. Folder Child Count - 0 in case of file
2. Item Child Count - Number of items inside the folder

[image]

Comment: I created a new view and selected both of those option, but the view still looks the same as the original. And I'm for sure looking at the new view. When I add other fields, they appear, but Item/Folder Child Count don't for some reason...

Comment: In the new view can you see folders? What values are displayed in the fields in mentioned

Comment: The default fields are still there (Name, Modified, Modified by), but the Item/Folder Child count doesn't appear, as if I didn't select them to be there. EDIT: I've noticed that when I go to the Tile View option instead of list it shows the number of items in each folder, but for list view it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Are you using a tabular style or something else?

Comment: The Document library layout is the new style, and not 'classic' sharepoint, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ok that might be the problem.. I tested only on the classic style

Comment: I switched to classic mode to see if there was a difference, and the new fields do appear! Is this a bug with the new document library's or something?

Comment: May be its not fully tested or we need to do a different approach in that style..